# How to send Push Notifications with Parse.com Cloudcode

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to send a Push Notification with Cloudcode on Parse.com.

The push notification should be sent to all android devices that are subscribed to a specific channel and trigger a service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a query to send a push to a channel. Just call [Parse.Push.send](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Push.html#.send) and add a channel array to the data object.

```
Parse.Push.send({
        channels: [ "channel_name" ],
        data: {
            alert: "Alert message"
        }
    }, {
        success: function () {
            response.success("Push was sent");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error("Could not send push " + error)
        }
    });
```

Be sure to not use spaces and Capital letters in channel names. The channel will not be added to the subscribed channels in the backend.

Comment: What if I want to send this message to everyone?
Should I set `channels` to "Everyone"?

Answer (score 4):

All you need is an installation query, along with an accompanying push. For example:

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.containedIn("user", userlist);
Parse.Push.send({
  where: pushQuery, 
  data: {
     alert: "Your push message here!"
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    response.success("pushed");
  }, error: function(error) {
   reponse.error("didn't push");
  }
});
```

That installation query can be a query based on a channel, and there are other specifications you can make for the push query, given in the documentation:

[Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options/iOS)

Answer (score 1):

1) Add

```
Parse.initialize("APPLICATION_ID", "JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
```

2) Enable Java scripts push notification in Parse.com

3) Download Java script project "parse-js-blank"

4) Create installation object with Channel

5) send request.

```
Parse.Push.send({
          channels: [ "Giants","Vaquar" ],
          data: {
            alert: "Vaquar Alert Message."
          }
        }, {
          success: function() {
            // Push was successful
          },
          error: function(error) {
            // Handle error
            alert("(error"+eval(error));
          }
        });
```

Reference: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications