# How to send push notification using javascript in parse?

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

we already implemented push notification concept using android but we are trying to send push notification using web application to mobile
here is my code

```
function authentication() {
debugger;
  Parse.$ = jQuery;

  // Initialize Parse with your Parse application javascript keys
  Parse.initialize("App key",
                   "javascript key");

debugger;      
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

debugger;
pushQuery.containedIn("channels", true);
Parse.Push.send({
  where: pushQuery, 
  data: {
     alert: "Your push message here!"
  }
}, {
  success: function() {

debugger;
    response.success("pushed");
  }, error: function(error) {
   reponse.error("didn't push");

debugger;
  }
})
```

We are got error

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/push 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught ReferenceError: reponse is not defined
```

We followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770167/how-to-send-push-notifications-with-parse-com-cloudcode) & Docs of [parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/JavaScript)
Plz guide to us

Comment: You have to write cloud code method to send push like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770167/how-to-send-push-notifications-with-parse-com-cloudcode?lq=1

Comment: your error is because of a typo: it's `reSponse` not `reponse` (though that's not the root cause of course...)

Comment: @Dunken same issue
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: well, its how the error says: the variable `response` isn't defined anywhere, I don't know the framework but it seems that `response` should be the first parameter to the `success` callback, so `{ success: function (response) { ...` could work

Comment: @vanhelgen we tried as you said but we got error like this
code: 115
message: "Client-initiated push isn't enabled."

Comment: So the `success` or `error` callbacks are indeed called so the push to the server should be successful or the error callback is called, so what is it you're trying to achieve after the push to the server? The `response...` lines only seem to be a placeholder for some action that should be done in either case. The docs explicitly state at the bottom that receiving push notifications is currently not supported by the JavaScript SDK, in case that's what you want.

Comment: @vanhelgen Actually we are done with sending push notification from mobile device to mobile device & parse to mobile using parse quires.
Now we are trying to send push notification from web application to mobile device using Javascript.
plz guide us

Comment: The callbacks seem to work so removing the `response...` lines will prevent the `ReferenceError` but the push message should have been sent to the server by the time the `success` callback is called, at least that's what every other framework does, so I don't see why it wouldn't push the message to the server even if you raise an error in the callbacks. If you're getting the `ReferenceError` in the `error` handler then the message has not been sent and the reason why is in the `error` parameter to said callback

Comment: @vanhelgen we tried as you said but we got
resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

parse-1.2.13.min.js:1 
POST https://api.parse.com/1/push 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @vanhelgen now we are getting this error
POST https://api.parse.com/1/push 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77058/discussion-between-user1838846-and-vanhelgen).