# Swift2 push when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to make a request every 15 minutes. Then I want to make a push notification to the user.

I use this code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // push
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge],categories:nil))


    // background fetch
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge], categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Complete");
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)

    getData();

}

func getData() -> Void {
    let p = PushService()
    p.Push("Changed")
}
```

It works fine but only one time.
And when I close this app via task manager there is no push.
So how I can send push notifications every 15 minutes even when the user closed my app. (like WhatsApp or another messenger)

I use a local push.

Comment: Have you tried using Parse for push notification handling? You can automate push notifications (up to whatever minute, hour, day you want) with Parse using Parse Cloud Code. I'd recommend that... Much easier. https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows

Comment: @nhgrif Thank you. So it is not possible to handle the situation I want?

Comment: @rinyfo So I can send push notifications every x minutes and receive them with my closed app?

Comment: Yes. For an update, a reminder, an action you want your user to take, whatever you chose. You need to write the Cloud Core code in javascript however. I can send you a gist of some cloud code I have for a timer if you're interested. @LaMiy.

Comment: @rinyfo4 This would be wonderful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by myself and others, I wouldn't recommend going about it in the app. Instead, you should use Parse.com Cloud Code for managing and setting Push Notifications: 
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/window

This links shows how to set up Cloud Code using your terminal. You can automate Push Notifications using Parse as well. Parse has relatively good documentation which can help you get started.

Here's the push notification homepage on Parse: https://parse.com/products/push

Here are the parse docs for Push Notifications which will take you through registering your app for Push Notifications as well: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications
Go down to "Sending Pushes" in the docs. This is where Parse will help you set up Push notifications with Cloud Code on Parse.

Once you set it up, go to your project, then "Core" and click jobs, and you'll get this screen (note, this is my project and I'm deleting posts. You can name this whatever you want): [image: This is my Parse for which I'm using Cloud Code]

Use this link for your push notification javascript code as a tutorial: [How to send Push Notifications with Parse.com Cloudcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770167/how-to-send-push-notifications-with-parse-com-cloudcode) it's a good example. On Parse, as the image I posted above shows, you can get specific on when you want the push notification to push to the user.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. Do I need a apple developer account?
Local pushes work without a developer account but it seems not to work without a certificate.

Comment: Yes you do. You need to set up the push notifications with Apple first whichever way you want to go about it (parse or not). In the docs Parse explains how to do this. (Ps, you can also chose to accept the question if it helped :) )

Comment: So it is not possible to send remote pushs without paying for the apple developer membership? -.-
Even if I only want to put the app on my own device?

Comment: Unfortunately not... It's because Apple requires making certificates/registering the app with your Apple developer account even before you submit it for review on the App store. Would definitely recommend getting an account though, especially if you want to send tests to friends through crashalytics/TestFlight, etc.

Comment: Okay thank you. 100$ developer license for a student just playing a bit with iOS apps is a bit too much.

Comment: I'm a student as well. It's worth it, especially for increasing your skill set and sending apps to friends and beyond! Would really recommend it. Anyways, good luck!